# Arremangarse-in context

Tags: verbos, significado-en-contexto

I believe "arremangarse" is to roll up one's sleeves both figuratively and literally. I want to use it figuratively. My Spanish friend told me that it is still better used in a figurative sense to convey the idea of undertaking a physical task such as washing the dishes (me arremango para fregar los platos).

I wanted to say "decidí arremangarme" in the context of studying. In other words, I decided to roll up my sleeves and start the year off on a good note by studying straight away. My friend suggested, perhaps, "ponerme de lleno" is better.

In addition, I have also used "hincar los codos", "empezar con  buen pie", "cambiar el chip" and other expressions in my piece.
As I like this verb and it works in English in this context {roll up my sleeves, pull up my socks), can I use it to talk about studying or is it odd?

Comment: Please look up words in the RAE and associated dictionaries. It also has slang meanings in the Panhispanico de dudas dictionary.  hincar los codos sounds like dig in my heels. Different image, same idea.

Comment: I have checked the RAE but it does not answer my questions about context. It explains the literal meaning and just''tomar una decision con resolucion''. It  does not explain if it can be used to get stuck in studying.

Comment: You need to post the definitions you find so we don't have to go look for them. Questions are supposed to be accompanied by research. Not my rule. An SE one.

Comment: Great. I will do that in future.tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say in your question, "arremangarse" refers to a **physical task** and studying is not. So "arremangarse para comenzar a estudiar", although possible, is not the best way. In any case, only if there is an implicit physical activity:

> Me arremangué para coger los libros y ponerme a estudiar

<sub>(Correct, but a bit bizarre)</sub>

#### Update after the comment

*it involves making a decision* but as long as it has a physical activity, the other ways are unnatural:

**Unnatural**

> Me arremango para rezar 
> Me arremango para pensar
> Me arremango para cantar

**Right**

> Me arremango y me hago una sopa
> Se arremangó y fue al banco
> Nos arremangamos y vamos

Comment: ok. But I thought from the RAE that it involved making a decision with determination so I thought it would work within this context. So, do I take it so that it is better to use something else unlike in English where it can mean to get to work,get stuck in in lots of ways

Comment: Answer updated.-

Comment: ok.That is great. I will use ''ponerse de lleno'' instead and save ''arremangarse'' for more physical tasks as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The DLE omits part of the meaning of "arremangarse" that is present in the definition given by Google/Oxford Languages:

> verbo transitivo verbo pronominal (**arremangarse**)
>  Tomar una decisión o
> **disponerse a realizar una acción de manera enérgica**.

It matches the meaning for "roll up your sleeves" that appears in the Cambridge Dictionary

> to prepare for hard work

"Arremangarse" does not imply a physical action per se but that you prepare yourself for doing your best in a difficult or hard task. It can be a physically hard task or a mentally hard one (stressful, time-consuming, complicated)

For me your sentence makes total sense. There is not a mandatory physical component in "arremangarse".

Apart from that, the DLE also mentions the word "resolución":

> 2. prnl. coloq. Tomar enérgicamente una resolución.

That kind of resolutions are typical during Xmas or at the beginning of the year: making a change in your usual behaviour.

> He decidido arremangarme y centrarme en los estudios para obtener buenos resultados

is perfectly fine and a lot of students have the same resolution ;-P

And last but not least, let me offer a counter-example for one of the answers because context is pretty important:

> Tenía miedo escénico pero me arremangué y canté un angelus en la catedral delante de 5000 personas.

Now you have an example using cantar (and rezar, being an angelus a prayer) that is completely natural and makes total sense.

Comment: That is very comprehensive and what I had originally thought and intended.I feel you are correct but I now feel reluctant to use it especially in an exam situation due to previous users' inputs but thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to say "decidí arremangarme" in the context of studying. In other words, ***I decided to roll up my sleeves and start the year off on a good note by studying straight away***.

I second your friend's suggestion:

> "***Decidí comenzar el año bien, concentrarme puesto de lleno a estudiar***"
>
> Or
>
> "***Decidí ponerme de lleno a estudiar y comenzar el año bien***"

A slightly more formal variant, also:

> '***Resolví comenzar bien el año, abocado a pleno*** [de lleno] ***al estudio*** (where 'abocar' conveys to devote oneself fully to something')

PS: If it serves a purpose for a more informal tone, an equivalent form to use in Argentina for the intended phrase (generally aligned with the idiom 'to roll-up one´s sleeves' to convey one´s resolution/disposition to do something), would go like:

> ***Este año decidí comenzarlo bien, 'ponerme las pilas' y dedicarme a estudiar*** [*de lleno* / *a full*]